# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n}}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n+1}}$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n}}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n+1}}$.
My approach is to do $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n}}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n+1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^{n}}{\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}+\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^{n}}$ but not sure what to do next.
How could I convert the $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}$ term into $\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^{n}$? Thanks.

Comment: Try the inverse multiplication of what you did, you should get a good result.  Specifically, multiply top and bottom of the original by $\left(\dfrac 23\right)^{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good general rule: divide numerator and denominator by the largest term:
$$\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n}}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n+1}}
  =\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3n}+1}$$
and I think you should now be able to see what happens as $n\to\infty$.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n}}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}+\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n+1}}
  =\dfrac1{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3n-1}+\frac{3}{2}}$$

Since $\dfrac{2}{3} <1$ , its limit will be zero.

Thus the answer is $\dfrac{1}{0+\frac{3}{2}}=\dfrac{2}{3}$